# CSS/Bootstrap div layout issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to position some elements within a div.

[Bootstrap fiddle](http://www.bootply.com/9CoRg3sbXq)  (upon click red icon)

[Desired end result](http://oi59.tinypic.com/2w6z7ma.jpg)

You may see some of the things I have attempted in the Bootply link. Normally for this situation I would split the image and text elements into seperate Div's and try to set them as `display:inline-block`.

This doesn't seem to be working, possibly because I'm using bootstrap, which has some default styling which applies to all Div's. Alternatively it may not be working because I'm a rank amateur in CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check my solution [Bootstrap fiddle](http://www.bootply.com/3AZJskv3p3)

Just added the class pull-left by the Image from Bootstrap and changed the css from .notification_msg.

```
<img class="notification_img pull-left" src="http://placehold.it/60x60">
```

`.notification_msg {
    padding-bottom: 30px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #D3D3D3;
}`.

Comment: Please include your code and explain it in the answer instead of just giving a link.

Comment: With this solution, the text has is vertically aligned to the top and has no spacing between the text and image. The only way around this that I know of would be to wrap the text elements in a Div and give it a class with `vertical-align: center` & `margin-left: 3px` for example. Is there any way this would be possible with your solution? I ask because this was linked to my original issue of using Divs to create this style.

Comment: Normally I would completely change structure of the code, because it's easier to handle it with divs and <hr> than borders. But you can just add `margin-right: 3px` in the `.notification_img` to solve the spacing. for the vertical-align you have solve it over div.

Comment: This is part of the issue i had, there seems to be an issue with bootstrap adding a 100% width to all divs, therefore putting the image in 1 div and the text in another, the text div gets pushed underneath. Adding `display:inline-block` to the containing div didn't seem to solve that.

Comment: Are you sure that you gave to the divs the grid classes. Without it don't work.

Comment: After giving it some thought i think i'll use your solution as it will allow me to add in extra functionality. See: http://www.bootply.com/AAetJWPwW4